# How to use span tags in php error statements

Tags: php

The echo statement is not printing when the answer does not equal to 8.So if the answer is other than 8 it should print in red "Please try again " underneath the textbox.All it shows is nothing when I click the register button.

```
   <?php

   session_start();
    $nameErr = "";


   $answer = $_POST['lastname'];

   if ($_POST['reg']){


     if ($answer != '8') {
        echo "<span style='color:red'>Please enter Correct Answer</span>";
     }
     }
    ?>
   <!Doctype html>
   <head>
   <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" 
   type="text/css">
   <link href="bootstrap/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Register.css">

   <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>

       <title> Register</title>



        </head>

        <html>
        <body>
        <form method="post" action="">
        What is 5 + 3 =<br>
        <input type="text" name="lastname"> 





       <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-3.5">
     <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"  value="Register" 
     type="submit" name="reg">
```

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438060/showing-all-errors-and-warnings

Comment: Your html  is messy, make sure you [validate](https://validator.w3.org/) and then apply php code to it

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `echo` in the `<body>` of the document. Also, `<html>` needs to be at the top.

```
<?php

session_start();
$nameErr = "";

?>
<!Doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" 
    type="text/css">
    <link href="bootstrap/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Register.css">
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    <title> Register</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="">
    What is 5 + 3 =<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname"> 
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['reg'])){
        $answer = $_POST['lastname'];
        if ($answer != '8') {
            echo "<span style='color:red'>Please enter Correct Answer</span>";
        }
    }
    ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-3.5">
            <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"  value="Register" type="submit" name="reg">
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried that by putting the html first and then the php code at the end but the message appears please enter correct answer even if I dont enter nothing in the textbox

Comment: If you enter nothing in the textbox, that's not the same as `8`, so you get the error message.

Comment: Nope the error message does not have the red colour so it should only come when I enter a value into the textbox click register and if it is not 8 then it should show the error message in red

Comment: Do you see the span if you use View Source? Use the DOM inspector to see what's overriding the style.

Comment: Maybe something in Twitter Bootstrap is doing it.

Comment: I deleted the Bootstrap but still no red coming up can I show you image of whats appearing .Can I put the error message in to a variable and then in the html use that within span tags

Comment: the php code is coming in green when I view in page source

Comment: So you see `color:green` instead of `color:red` in the source? I have no idea where that could be coming from.

Comment: Yes, you can put the error message in a variable, but I can't see any reason why that would make a difference.

Comment: nope you know how code gets commented out as green that was showing

Comment: That's just browser highlighting to make the source code easier to read, it's irrelevant. Do you see `<span style="color:red">` in the source code? If so, then this is working. You can use the DOM inspector to see why the rendered color isn't red. DevTools has lots of tools to help you debug your HTML, I can't teach you how to do it here.

Answer (score 0):

You print the error span above the actual HTML code. Just move the if statement down. Like that:

```
...
<div class="row">
<?php
if ($answer != '8') {
    echo "<span style='color:red'>Please enter Correct Answer</span>";
}
?>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-3.5">
...
```

Comment: @MajedMahmood - yes